# Is light send from the top of a ship to deck different when the ship is moving or not?

Tags: special-relativity

If you drop a ball from the top downwards to the deck it will follow a rather straigth line because the ball gets also a force horizontaly because the ship is moving. That is the cause in history why people didn't thougt that the earth itself is moving.

But I think light can't be pushed so it seems that a laserbeam not exactly follows the same path if the ship is moving or not. Probably because of the short distance it will be hard to measure. But the question is of course more principle.

So does is make a difference if the ship is moving or not?

Comment: Neglecting air resistance, the ball and the photon will land in the same spot.

Comment: The ball doesn't get a "force" along the direction of motion, it gets "initial velocity".

Comment: Lookup "aberration of starlight"

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the ship is moving at constant speed to the right. And consider the situation from the point of view of someone standing on board of the ship. From this person's point of view, the ship is at rest. (She will see the sea moving to the left *with respect to her and the ship*.) So when she sends a beam of light from the top downwards, it will arrive at the spot on the deck that is exactly below the point where she emitted it.

Now consider the situation in which you are looking at the moving ship from an island. The light should still arrive at the spot exactly below the point where the light is emitted, so from your viewpoint it will ideed look as if the light has *inherited* some momentum from the movement of the ship.

So from your point of view the light has some velocity in the direction in which the ship is moving. However, since the speed of light must be the same in all inertial frames of reference (this is the special theory of relativity), this means that the light must, from your point of view, have a smaller velocity in the vertical direction. Then you will probably realize that it will take longer for the light to reach the deck of the ship. This is exactly where time dilatation comes from. The person on the ship will have a different measure of time than you have when standing on the island. What a mysterious world!

Comment: I understand that from the point of view from the island due to time dilatation there is a difference. But how is it possible that a photon send at time t=1 arrives at the same spot at t=2 while the ship is sailing with a certain speed?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking why it is that the light does not fall on the deck a little bit 'behind' the spot where is was emitted, because of the movement of the ship. But you got to understand that for the people *on* the schip nothing changes. Since they are always at rest with respect tot themselves. So the light will always arrive exactly below the spot of emission. Then, converting back to the reference system of someone watching from the island, we find that the light must gain some velocity in the direction in which the schip is moving.

Comment: Ok, but how does it come that people on the ship can't see any difference? When it was a massive ball it would have some velocity of the direction with the ship. But you can't speed up light or can it....?

Comment: You are correct that you cannot speed up light. But you can speed it up in some direction, if you slow it down in the perpendicular direction, in such a way that the total velocity does not change. This is exactly what happens.